# (Java) javafx не отображаются данные в treeTableView

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть элемент treeTableView в котором я хочу отобразить дерево из элементов типа String.

Для этого я создаю treeTableView через javafx (через файл с параметрами в main.fxml) и дальше хочу заполнить это дерево данными.

Для этого использую такой код:

```
public void init(){
    
    //Получить treeTableViewFileName
    TreeTableView<String> treeTableViewFileName = controller.getTreeTableViewFileName();
    
    //Creating tree items
    TreeItem<String> childNode1 = new TreeItem<>("Child Node 1");
    TreeItem<String> childNode2 = new TreeItem<>("Child Node 2");
    TreeItem<String> childNode3 = new TreeItem<>("Child Node 3");
    
    //Creating the root element
    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("Root");
    root.setExpanded(true);
    
    //Adding tree items to the root
    root.getChildren().setAll(childNode1, childNode2, childNode3);        

    //В колонку добавить CellValueFactory
    TreeTableColumn<String, String> column1 = controller.getTreeColumnFileName();
    column1.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    
    treeTableViewFileName.setRoot(root); //Добавить root
    treeTableViewFileName.setShowRoot(true); //Разрешить отображение root   

    //Запретить возможность менять размер колонки
    column1.setResizable(false);

    //Запретить возможность сортировать значения в колонке
    column1.setSortable(false);
    
    System.out.println("stop");
}
```

При этом получается, что таблица создается, но ничего не отображается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом на разных других сайтах видел примеры, когда происходит создание treeTableView на основе root элемента, вот таким образом:

```
TreeTableView<String> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>(root);
```

Мне такое не подходит, потому что создание идет через файл main.fxml, а сами данные мне необходимо добавлять по мере работы программы. Во всех примерах, что я видел был именно такой подход: создание таблицы на основе root.

Часть кода из main.fxml:

```
<Pane fx:id="pane3" prefHeight="280.0" prefWidth="917.0">
     <children>
        <TreeTableView fx:id="treeTableViewFileName" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="240.0" prefWidth="227.0">
          <columns>
            <TreeTableColumn fx:id="treeColumnFileName" prefWidth="199.0" text="FileName" />
          </columns>
        </TreeTableView>
     </children>
  </Pane>
```

Подскажите как можно организовать отображение данных в моем случае? Заранее спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел такое решение: можно попробовать сделать дополнительный класс, например назвав его Employee или как угодно, он нужен, чтобы отображать данные в строках таблицы.

Этот класс будет выглядеть так:

```
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

public class Employee {
    
    private final ObjectProperty<String> name;
    
    public Employee (String name) {
        this.name = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        this.name.set(name);
    }
    
    public final ObjectProperty<String> nameProperty() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Затем нужно выполнить 2 стадии: 1) инициализация и 2) ввод данных.

Стадия 1:

```
//Получить treeTableViewFileName
TreeTableView<Employee> treeTableViewFileName = controller.getTreeTableViewFileName();
        
//В колонку добавить TreeItemPropertyValueFactory
TreeTableColumn<Employee, String> column1 = (TreeTableColumn) treeTableViewFileName.getColumns().get(0);
column1.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<Employee, String ("name"));
        
//Разрешить отображение root 
treeTableViewFileName.setShowRoot(true);
```

Стадия 2:

```
//Создать root элемент
Employee rootEmp = new Employee("root");

//Создать элементы child
Employee emp1 = new Employee("asdadsa");
Employee emp2 = new Employee("asdadsa");
Employee emp3 = new Employee("asdadsa");
                    
TreeItem<Employee> childNode1 = new TreeItem<>(emp1);
TreeItem<Employee> childNode2 = new TreeItem<>(emp2);                   
TreeItem<Employee> childNode3 = new TreeItem<>(emp3);

TreeItem<Employee> root = new TreeItem<>(rootEmp);
root.setExpanded(true);

root.getChildren().setAll(childNode1, childNode2, childNode3);        

//Так как я произвожу данные действия в другом потоке, то нужно сделать обновление в потоке javafx
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    treeTableViewFileName.setRoot(root); //Добавить root и данные
});
```

Основная часть из main.fxml:

```
<Pane fx:id="pane3" prefHeight="280.0" prefWidth="917.0">
    <children>
        <TreeTableView fx:id="treeTableViewFileName" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="240.0" prefWidth="227.0">
            <columns>
                <TreeTableColumn fx:id="treeColumnFileName" prefWidth="199.0" text="FileName" />
            </columns>
        </TreeTableView>
    </children>
</Pane>
```

Мой контроллер Controller_MainGUI:

```
public class Controller_MainGUI {

    @FXML
    private TreeTableView treeTableViewFileName;

    @FXML
    private TreeTableColumn treeColumnFileName;
    
    public TreeTableView getTreeTableViewFileName(){
        return this.treeTableViewFileName;
    }
    
    public TreeTableColumn getTreeColumnFileName(){
        return this.treeColumnFileName;
    }
}
```

И там самым на выходе мы получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]